# Bash - arithmetic in array index

Tags: arrays, bash, arithmetic-expressions

Say I have an array `arr` and an index `x`. How do I assign something to the array at index x+1? I'm getting bugs by trying the following, if one of them is correct I'd love to know which one and if not what am I doing wrong?

```
arr[$x+1]="hi"      # Doesn't work
arr[$((x+1))]="hi"  # Nope
```

Comment: Both work correctly. GNU Bash 4.2.37(1).

Comment: References: The [Bash guide for beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) says an array index "is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a positive number."  [Arithmetic expressions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_05) are whatever can go inside `$(( ))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there.

```
arr[(($x+1))]="hi"
```

Comment: So why would I be getting this: 

    ./win.bash: line 114: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    ./win.bash: line 114: `                    let game[(($j+1))]=$tmp'

Comment: You're not using bash as your interpreter. Or you're using an old version.

Comment: bash --version: v 4.1.2(1)

Comment: `x` is neither a number nor a variable.

Comment: `x` isn't a variable? It's my loop index...
`for (( x=0; x<total; x+=2 ))`
And about the version problem, nevermind... I found out `x` is empty when the bug is reached

Comment: Regarding whether or not `x` needs dereferenced, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40104348/915044